# Where is mongoid.yml?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I just installed mongoid. I tried their sample code, it raised a beautiful error with a recommendation "Double check your mongid.yml..." So I went to read their intro at mongoid.org, [where they say](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html): "Mongoid configuration can be done through a `mongoid.yml`". But I dig it how everyone takes for granted that the noob like me will know where the Heaven that mongoid.yml is. Sure, I could just `find -name mongoid.yml`, but isn't this weird? Is this a kind of harrowing that every new Mongoid user have to go through?

Edit: OK., this is exactly what I've sporked from Mongoid website.

```
require 'mongoid'

class Human
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embeds_many :interests
end

class Interest
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :content, type: String
  embedded_in :human
end

ccfu = Human.where( name: "John Doe" )
ccfu.interests.create( content: "criminal activity" )
```

Comment: I like the sentence - *it raised a beautiful error*.. :D

Comment: Never seen a more beautiful one: Mongoid::Errors::NoSessionConfig: 
Problem:
  No configuration could be found for a session named 'default'.
Summary:
  When attempting to create the new session, Mongoid could not find a session configuration for the name: 'default'. This is necessary in order to know the host, port, and options needed to connect.
Resolution:
  Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure under the sessions key that a configuration exists for 'default'. If you have set the configuration programatically, ensure that 'default' exists in the configuration hash.

Comment: Yes! the error itself guides you where to fix.. selfservice!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not using Ruby on Rails you can put `mongoid.yml` wherever you like and then in your code you can load it using the `load!` method:

```
Mongoid.load!('path/to/mongoid.yml', :development)
```

Or:

```
ENV['MONGOID_ENV'] = 'development'
Mongoid.load!('path/to/mongoid.yml')
```

On Ruby on Rails it is inside the `config` directory.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But, I'm curious, although I never used `#load!` method, it still went on about mongoid.yml, so I figured one was loaded by default from somewhere.

Comment: No configuration is loaded by default (check `Mongoid.sessions`). The error messages are just misleading, I think, since you can avoid using a `mongoid.yml` file and configure Mongoid programmatically.